# fancybox is opening one time, and the next time it gives an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, fancybox

`fancybox` is opening only one time.  The next time it produces an error. I have list of companies and function calling `onClick`:

```
function Singin(jobid) {
    $.fancybox({
        href: "/Contact/PopBid?jobid=" + jobid,
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'easingIn': 'easeOutBack',
        'easingOut': 'easeInBack',
        'width': 850,
        'height': 394,
        **success: function () {
            parent.$.fancybox.close();
            //Do stuff**                      if i remove this then get error on Height
        }

    });

}
```

Log:

```
jquery.min.js (line 141)

TypeError: $.fancybox is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

success: function () {
```

**EDIT** (moved from comments):

The files used :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="../../Scripts/Fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script> !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>'); </script>
<script src="../../Scripts/Fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/Fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: OK, I got it :) 1.3.4

Comment: i have attached these Scripts and Css

Comment: Can't reproduce error: http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/cA6Yk/8/. Please, make JSFiddle of problem and we try to help you.

Comment: You set the tag fancybox-2 but you are using fancybox v1.3.4

Comment: `success` is not a fancybox API option hence the error .... remove it but also remove the trailing comma after `'height': 394, //<-- remove comma from last option`.